# Spring boot rabbitmq integration problems

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-boot

i am attempting to do this tutorial on springboot with rabbitmq integration.When i declare the receiver bean i cannot Autowire the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext bean making my whole receiver class unusable as i declare it as a bean in the main method class.

The whole tutorial is in the link below.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/

Thanks..

Comment: Works for me (the complete code is here: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-rabbitmq/tree/master/complete). Why did you tag the question as "jms" (maybe it means you are doing something other than what is in the guide)? What did you do and how did it fail?

Comment: Hey i mistakenly tagged that,the only difference is i am using it with maven and not gradle.i have seen the pom file in the project and have tried to adapt it to mine.maybe thats the problem.will try and do the project clean following this tutorial.

Comment: it doesn't seem to AnnotationConfigApplicationContext bean.its says no qualifying bean of type org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext found for dependency.

Comment: Try using the interface `ApplicationContext` instead of the concrete class `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`. It might be that Spring Boot did change its own custom implementation of the application context class.

Comment: You need `ConfigurableApplicationContext` to get the `close()` method. But the sample in the guide still works fine, so I suggest the OP provide more detail on what he did different to the rest of us.

Comment: Hello after autowiring ConfigurableApplicationContext i am able to close  after sending to queue.Thank you as this worked for me :) .